# Which is better/more efficient in coffeescript when running a for loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, coffeescript

There are two functionally equivalent ways of writing the following function in javascript, which is better or more efficient, and why?

```
(str) ->
  s = 0
  for i in [0...str.length]
    s += str.charCodeAt i 
  s
```

or

```
(str) ->
  s = 0
  for i in str
    s += i.charCodeAt 0 
  s
```

Aside: Can you suggest any other methods of doing this?

Edit: According to JSPerf, the first is faster: http://jsperf.com/coffee-for-loop-speed-test - why is this?

Comment: It is about one microsecond faster (on my machine), I'll give you that... (0.533ms vs 1.64ms)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first is both more elegant and more efficient. The second copies each character of the string to a separate string unnecessarily, before converting it to a `charCode`.

Comment: I had initially wondered if getting the character code of a position in a string increased in time depending on the length of the string, but come to think of it, if there was, the difference would be negligible compared to the time taken to create individual strings for each character. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with [functional programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming)? Coffeescript + [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) working together are pretty awesome. You can use either the native `Array#reduce` defined on ECMAScript 5 or the underscore function. Example for the first:

```
(s.charCodeAt(0) for s in "hello").reduce((acc, x) -> acc + x) # 532
```